# Is there a better way of displaying JSON data from API in angular datatable?

Tags: html, angular, datatable

I am using angular data table and I am able to get the data from api,but data table is showing "no records" message even when the data is there and when I am trying to sort them ,the data is going away.

```js
export class SalesComponent implements OnInit {
          salesRepData: any = []; //defining Array
          constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        
          }
          title = 'angulardatatables';
          dtOptions: any = [];
          ngOnInit() {
            this.dtOptions = {
              pagingType: 'full_numbers',
              pageLength: 3,
              processing: true,
            };
            this.fetchPosts();
          }
          private fetchPosts() {
            this.http
              .get('https:demo/api')
              .subscribe(posts => {
                if (posts) {
                  this.salesRepData = posts;
                }
              });``
            }
          }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm row-border hover" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              Sales Rep
            </th>
            <th>
              Total Commission
            </th>
            <th>
              Commission earned
            </th>
            <th>
              Commission pending
            </th>
            <th>Commission paid</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let sale of salesRepData">
            <td>
              {{sale.salesrepId}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{sale.totalCommission}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{sale.commissionEarned}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{sale.commissionPending}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{sale.commissionPaid}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: after this.salesRepData = posts; add console.log(this.salesRepData) and look in the console and see if you have data

Comment: yes data is coming and it is being displayed in the datatable as well but it is still showing no records available at the bottom of the data table

Comment: Can you create an angular sandbox?  https://codesandbox.io or similar and share?

Comment: https://therichpost.com/angular-datatables-with-custom-button-event-click-open-bootstrap-modal-popup/  In the data table, there is sorting option from the library itself. This sorting thing is working when I am passing hard coded data, but it is not working when I am using api to do the same

Comment: there are thousands of "datatable", I should think you use a jQuery data table but I don't know. here there a link that can be util: https://medium.com/@yankipranata_21138/full-tutorial-angular-datatable-for-beginner-9cca5585e5d8